# How to validate JWT token in asp .net 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt

I am pretty new to jwt in general. I have a different server that is doing the whole login stuff and proving a signed jwt to my angular client.

I've built an asp.net rest-api, that the angular client uses to get data. But i can not get the authorization configured and i am not sure, what i am doing wrong.

My JWT looks like this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzM4NCIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5Lm15YXBwbGljYXRpb24ubmV0Iiwic3ViIjoiMjg3YjE0YzUtYTYyMS00ODY3LWEzN2UtN2FjOTllNDJiYWJmIiwiYXVkIjoiYWJjMTIzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzcyOTE3NTQxLCJpYXQiOjE3NzI5MTY2NDEsIm5vbmNlIjoiVlZkbVprd3dTelJMWkZSZmQwdGtTVWw0T0ZsdGFYUXVObDh4UlZObWQwdFpRMHRWWjFseE5EQnplakptIiwidXNlcmluZm8iOnsiaWQiOiIyODdiMTRjNS1hNjIxLTQ4NjctYTM3ZS03YWM5OWU0MmJhYmYiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJNeVVzZXIiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6Ik15VXNlckxhc3ROYW1lIiwibG9naW5FbWFpbCI6IiJ9fQ.ZTd_QX3domPvqYvLyjTvbN3MpF4P384W-Jc61uWaSMCUEYCXdZfRQVVHYcqof9OIs3Br1ZEn9ZYeEI3prY1txHNZiJse9pKTnUyjfvEwr9MGsAco9wehooLyH5LKKheSVSK2_i4lhwNUoO4jJrQouq6akWyCrLj3b-xdf_nTET5LMKVT6WWyryHLnK7EaKP6APQYzp5tcOqpSLeTV-MqsO_k4odTFS2sNUE5XpZTSyl-Kv1TfiLa5-J2OzUTiy5kav5uK-eJmiyVlMhz09S3eyXJvGN52F8qcbz3dGo9-sV00k-I9bzAKABYeTI8vJB6fBHkXIVFoLQMJmzNZ-sxfYI6vb4hNSYbf_QpTJ94X5nTg8x5uTr3z8GSUNOvMAi7Ed1pS9W-Y0lxPmziIGiqon9ejoe1xAWROkQ7uqug6yft46h_tYOqnN9icEHj_s6EW2cFg19xq6MIof1D1NDsacN7vnq8Ge63yFdKUlVdTmwe5rnSZgATZSfbOq0DBi1dikbZPJS2TTir5wnyrajxk-OydSvU90HWZcbUX2AgX-5rSkIw19SFU7Laamd-aw68C5a8SvUnlxFqn7vqJZ42Uw3Vz3z79nulEcRS7T-BIe6zRW7-cZlfeyEPme-k5B-2706s108klXnEyouySUtJ0ORkDfPutXZ-_96Lf4SMWow
```

At this website https://jwt.io/ i am able to manually validate the token with the public key

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My Program.cs looks like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = "https://identity.myapplication.net",
        ValidAudience = "abc123",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "<Public Key>"))
    };
});
```

The controller look like this

```
        [HttpGet, Authorize]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public ActionResult<ICollection<DemoRequest>> Get()
        {
            //TODO: get information of requesting user
            IQueryable<DemoRequest> query = dbContext.DemoRequests.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.Created);
            return Ok(query.ToList());
        }
```

My goal is to get the information of the requesting user in my controller to return user related data, check permissions and so on.

My request from insomnia always returns code 401 with the token.
[image]

I am not sure, if the `TokenValidationParameters` are working as i expect. I have tried setting `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to false and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. As far as i know this is the 'old way' and Microsoft introduced some simplifications with asp.net7. Maybe some one can help me get them to work.

This artikel by Nicklas Millard helped me getting this working [link](https://blog.devgenius.io/jwt-authentication-in-asp-net-core-e67dca9ae3e8).

First I needed to add a singleton service that provides my RSA Security Key

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RsaSecurityKey>(provider =>
{
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(
        source: Convert.FromBase64String(
            "<Public Key>"
        ), out int _);
    return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
});
```

And afterwards I have added the authentication scheme "Asymmetric" and set the `IssuerSigningKey` to the security key.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("Asymmetric",options =>
{
    SecurityKey rsa = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = "https://identity.myapplication.net",
        ValidAudience = "abc123",
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = rsa
    };
});
```

This works but i think there is still a more 'modern' answer to this.